# Cannot add dynamic id to jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the follwing jquery

```
var wrapperClass        = 'tableAccordionWrapper';
var template            = 'tableInput.html';

addTableInput = function(){
    var int;
    var wrapper = $('<li />');
    wrapper.addClass(wrapperClass);
    wrapper.attr('id','table1');
    var href = $('<a href="#">Table xx</a>');
    var parentWrapper = $('#selectedTables .sub-content .input-controls');
    $.ajax({
        url:        template,
        dataType:   'html',
        success: function(data){
            wrapper.append(href);
            $(data).appendTo(wrapper).insertBefore(parentWrapper);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Something went wrong')
        },
        complete: function(){
            int = $('.tableAccordionWrapper').length; 
            console.log(int);
        }
    });
}
```

The `addClass` function is being passed to the li element fine. But strangely not the `attr add id`. When I debug, I can see that the id seems to temporarily exist for the node but stepping out of debug, the element only retains the class name.

I even tried chaining the function like so:

`wrapper.addClass(wrapperClass).attr('id','table1');`

And also tried:

`wrapper.attr('tabindex','1');`

To see if it was a problem with the attribute. But only classname seems to be being passed to the LI element.

I also tried to pass the `wrapper.attr('id','table1')` function inside the ajax success and complete functions.

[image]

*My problem*

I have a large chunk of html which forms part of a form. On dom ready a single block of html is injected via ajax. The user can insert additional blocks, at this point I create a wrapper for the form elements, and I need some way to count the current elements, or increment an integer to add to the ID of the LI so that the child elements will be unique.

If this requires a working jsfiddle example I can try and set one up.

*EDIT*

I am wondering if it is something to do with the way I am creating the LI node in jquery?

```
var wrapper = $('<li />');
```

*EDIT*

HTML block:

```
<label for="tableDescription1" class="control col-md-6">Table description
    <input type="text" name="tableDescription1" class="mandatory fullWidth">
</label>
<label for="rowCount1" class="control">Row count
    <input type="text" name="rowCount1" value="">
</label>
<p class="control">Is there a Pre-Environment</p>
<span class="controls-stacked">
    <label class="control radio">
        <input type="radio" name="preEnvironment1" type="radio" value="Y" class="hiddenInput" checked />
        <span class="control-indicator"></span>
        Yes
    </label>
    <label class="control radio">
        <input type="radio" name="preEnvironment1" type="radio" value="N" class="hiddenInput" />
        <span class="control-indicator"></span>
        No
    </label>
</span>
```

The names in the form block are unique, and so they need to be incremented when a new block of html is added via ajax.

For example rowCount1 will need to be incremented to rowCount2 when the second block of html is injected.

Comment: Why do you even need to add an ID??? You could just keep a counter and increment it by 1 each element that is created. You know you can count elements without them having an id right?

Comment: @Milney of course, I don't have to use an ID. I also tried to increment the classname, and add my own attr data-id but neither worked.

Comment: I don't understand your problem... they can all have the same class name (that does not have to be unique)... then you can simply count them with $("body").find(".className").length (note using find() as you mentioned they are dynamically added)

Comment: No need to use an ID, or to increment anything...

Comment: @Santi in new versions (5-6) of ES `int` is not a reserved word anymore.

Comment: @Milney maybe you need to see the HTML. I will add it.

Comment: @lharby what is your actual problem? You want to count the elements? you can use the code I posted to get all elements with that class? what is the problem?

Comment: @kosmos - Ah, I see that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). Though to be honest, `int` as a variable name still makes my inner programmer cringe.

Comment: I have changed the int name, thanks for that.

Comment: @Santi Yes I think the same and I consider it a bad practice, but I had to comment it to avoid wrong information here. I've checked it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar 

Comment: @lharby Can you wrap the html inside a div? So in your ajax success `$(data)` will be an unique element and you could append a `data-*` attribute to make your counter.

Comment: There is defo no issue dynamically adding an `id`. https://jsfiddle.net/1omvgo8z/ (check the created element with dev tools)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see you adding `wrapper` to the page at any point

Comment: This question needs a [mcve] to demonstrate the exact problem.

Comment: @Santi `$(data).appendTo(wrapper).insertBefore(parentWrapper);` however I think there may be an error in that code, I am trying to debug now.

Comment: @Iharby that won't do anything with `wrapper`. `insertBefore()` in that line is referring to `$(data)`... [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/t3z8ue03/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Issue:**

You're never adding `wrapper` to the page. I'm assuming this line was *meant* to do that:

```
$(data).appendTo(wrapper).insertBefore(parentWrapper);
```

To preserve method-chaining, jQuery methods like [`appendTo(`*`target`*`)`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) do not return the target, but rather the preceding element. With that in mind, you'll notice that the example above is really just doing `$(data).insertBefore(parentWrapper)` - the `appendTo` not serving much of a purpose.

I've made [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/t3z8ue03/) to demonstrate.

---

**The Solution:**

Try something like this instead:

```
wrapper.append(data).insertBefore(parentWrapper);
```

In this example, we've shuffled things a bit so that the entire line is now referring to *`wrapper`*, instead of *`data`*.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had just worked that out at the same time roughly, and it seems to be working now.